# Java how to see from thread if main is still running or not?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework

So I'm making my very first play framework application, and I'm launching a thread, when any of the pages is loaded at first time. This works fine, but problem is, that when my application stops, the thread doesn't stop with it. In this thread I have server socket witch doesn't get released, when I restart my program so I'm assuming that my thread doesn't exit with it. So how can I force my thread to stop when my application exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works fine, but problem is, that when my application stops, the thread doesn't stop with it.

(Actually, you mean that your application isn't stopping.  If the application stops, then all threads are stopped, and all sockets that the application owns are closed.)

The simple way to deal with this is to mark the worker thread as a "daemon thread" by calling `setDaemon(true)` on the `Thread` before it is started.

Under normal circumstances, the JVM shuts down when either some thread calls `System.exit(...)`, or the last non-daemon thread terminates.  If you are spawning worker threads that don't terminate, they will cause the JVM to keep running after your "main" thread has terminated.  Marking them as daemon will avoid this.

---

It is good practice to ensure that sockets are closed when the thread that created them is terminated.  However, that is not what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify your problem and provide example code?

If you have created a GUI using Swing or AWT not handling the windowClosing event will cause the GUI to close but application to remain running in the console/JRE.